# Encrypt using reapeting XOR

Tags: java, encryption, xor

i have to encrypy a string using repeating XOR with the KEY:"ICE".
I think that i made a correct algorith to do it but the solution of the problem has 5 byte less then my calculated Hex string, why? Until this 5 bytes more the string are equals.

Did i miss something how to do repeating XOR?

```
public class ES5 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String str1 = "Burning 'em, if you ain't quick and nimble";
        String str2 = "I go crazy when I hear a cymbal";
        String correct1 = "0b3637272a2b2e63622c2e69692a23693a2a3c6324202d623d63343c2a2622632427276527";

        byte[] cr = Encript(str1.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8),"ICE");

        String cr22 = HexFormat.of().formatHex(cr);
        System.out.println(cr22);
        System.out.println(correct1);

    }
    private static byte doXOR(byte b, byte b1) {
        return (byte) (b^b1);
    }

    private static byte[] Encript(byte[] bt1, String ice) {
        int x = 0;
        byte[] rt = new byte[bt1.length];
        for (int i=0;i< bt1.length;i++){
            rt[i] = doXOR(bt1[i],(byte) (ice.charAt(x) & 0x00FF));
            x++;
            if(x==3)x=0;
        }
        return  rt;
    }
}
```

Comment: Everything looks relatively good at first glance. Only `correct1` is wrong and should (at least) have the double length of `str1` - 5 bytes are missing. You can also try Arrays.equals and Arrays.toString.

Comment: Calling _i have to encrypy a string using repeating XOR_ 'encryption' is a bit like tossing a raw egg on a plate and calling that 'cooking'. So misleading it's effectively lying.

Comment: Your `correct1` string contains 37 characters (as in, 74 nibbles, each nibble is half a character. 74 / 2 = 37). The `str1` string is 42 characters long. The problem is, I don't know where you got `correct1` from, but __it is incorrect__. Perhaps you copy/pasted it from somewhere else and you forgot to paste the final 10 nibbles, or, the person who made whatever you pasted it from made that mistake.

Comment: This code is 'fine', except for the one caveat that the style is 'bad' (typos, and wrong capitalization), and calling this 'encrypt' is an affront to sanity. Rename your method to `private static byte[] sequentialXor(` instead of `Encript` would fix those issues.

Comment: I would pass your key in as a byte array too. Don't hardcode the 'wrapping' - there's no need. Also, no need to 'unsign' - you're just doing bit-ops

Comment: @rzwitserloot the algorithm was correct but the string was wrong. I thought that the 2 strings that i had to encrypt was 2 different, but the original string was split in 2 line. My bad, but i leave the question for who is in search of a similar algorithm.

Comment: @rzwitserloot This isn't meant to be "encryption"; it's an exercise from the [Cryptopals challenges.](https://www.cryptopals.com/sets/1/challenges/5)

Comment: Yes, i'm trying this for the first time. So, i wrote encrypt cause the text says it.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. The String contains characters, and XOR works on bytes.
That's why the first thing is to run String.getBytes() to receive a byte array.

Here, depending on the characters and their encoding the amount of bytes can be more than the amount of characters. You may want to print and compare the numbers already.

Then you perform XOR on the bytes, which may bring you into a completely different area for characters - so you cannot rely on `new String(byte[])` at all. Instead you have to create a HEX string representation of the byte[].

Finally compare this HEX string with the value in correct. To me that string already looks like a HEX representation, so do not apply HEX again.